# My android app does not support android version 13 for One Plus Nord

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, version, google-play-console

I'm developing a flutter app and I have recently updated it and it stopped working on my One Plus Nord. after realizing it is working on Galaxy phones I found that in Google Play Console

I don't understand why it support Android v.13 but not One Plus's.
I don't know if it's related but my minSdkVersion is 20 (can't be lower because of the Google Maps API).

I wonder what might be the problem and what are the ways to fix it.

I haven't really tried to solve it in any way because I'm pretty new to flutter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.